# Flutter - clip only one side of a ListView

Tags: flutter

I need to clip only the top of a ListView. I need to have `clipBehavior: clip.none` so that it doesn't clip the horizontal sides, then clip the top myself. Is this possible? The usage will be something like this:

```
ClipPath(
    clipper: TopClipper(),
    child: ListView.builder(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      controller: _scrollController,
      padding: PAD_S_ALL,
      itemCount: searchResults.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Result(
          _sizingInfo,
          index: index,
          isLast: index == searchResults.length - 1,
          selectedIndexBuilder: _selectedIndexBuilder,
          model: SearchResultModel(searchResults[index]),
          vm: vm,
        );
      },
    ));
```